# why jquery .change() not working with jquery plugin jquery.selectbox-0.6.1.js?

Tags: jquery, select

I am trying to use jquery.selectbox-0.6.1.js plugin for drop-down.

I want to perform some operation on change event on selectbox but on change event of

selectbox nothing is happening..I don't know why this happening to me.

here is my code:

```
<select id="per-page-select">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option> 

         $('#per-page-select').selectbox().change(function() 
    {
          window.location = pager_url.replace('!REPLACEPAGE!', $(this).val());
    });
```

The above code does not works but if I remove .selectbox() then code works fine.

```
$('#per-page-select').change(function() 
    {
          window.location = pager_url.replace('!REPLACEPAGE!', $(this).val());
    });
```

Above code works because here I have not used selectbox().

here is code  for jquery.selectbox-0.6.1.js

```
jQuery.fn.selectbox = function(options){
    /* Default settings */
    var settings = {
        className: 'jquery-selectbox',
        animationSpeed: "normal",
        listboxMaxSize: 10,
        replaceInvisible: false
    };
    var commonClass = 'jquery-custom-selectboxes-replaced';
    var listOpen = false;
    var showList = function(listObj) {
        var selectbox = listObj.parents('.' + settings.className + '');
        listObj.slideDown(settings.animationSpeed, function(){
            listOpen = true;
        });
        selectbox.addClass('selecthover');
        jQuery(document).bind('click', onBlurList);
        return listObj;
    }
    var hideList = function(listObj) {
        var selectbox = listObj.parents('.' + settings.className + '');
        listObj.slideUp(settings.animationSpeed, function(){
            listOpen = false;
            jQuery(this).parents('.' + settings.className + '').removeClass('selecthover');
        });
        jQuery(document).unbind('click', onBlurList);
        return listObj;
    }
    var onBlurList = function(e) {
        var trgt = e.target;
        var currentListElements = jQuery('.' + settings.className + '-list:visible').parent().find('*').andSelf();
        if(jQuery.inArray(trgt, currentListElements)<0 && listOpen) {
            hideList( jQuery('.' + commonClass + '-list') );
            jQuery('.indented .jquery-selectbox').addClass('hidden');
        }
        return false;
    }

    /* Processing settings */
    settings = jQuery.extend(settings, options || {});
    /* Wrapping all passed elements */
    return this.each(function() {
        var _this = jQuery(this);
        if(_this.filter(':visible').length == 0 && !settings.replaceInvisible)
            return;
        var replacement = jQuery(
            '<div class="' + settings.className + ' ' + commonClass + '">' +
                '<div class="' + settings.className + '-moreButton" />' +
                '<div class="' + settings.className + '-list ' + commonClass + '-list" />' +
                '<span class="' + settings.className + '-currentItem" />' +
            '</div>'
        );
        jQuery('option', _this).each(function(k,v){
            var v = jQuery(v);
            var listElement =  jQuery('<span class="' + settings.className + '-item value-'+v.val()+' item-'+k+'">' + v.text() + '</span>');   
            listElement.click(function(){                
                var thisListElement = jQuery(this);
                var thisReplacment = thisListElement.parents('.'+settings.className);
                var thisIndex = thisListElement[0].className.split(' ');
                for( k1 in thisIndex ) {
                    if(/^item-[0-9]+$/.test(thisIndex[k1])) {
                        thisIndex = parseInt(thisIndex[k1].replace('item-',''), 10);
                        break;
                    }
                };
                var thisValue = thisListElement[0].className.split(' ');
                for( k1 in thisValue ) {
                    if(/^value-.+$/.test(thisValue[k1])) {
                        thisValue = thisValue[k1].replace('value-','');
                        break;
                    }
                };                
                thisReplacment
                    .find('.' + settings.className + '-currentItem')
                    .text(thisListElement.text())
                    .addClass('activated');
                    jQuery('.indented .jquery-selectbox').addClass('hidden');
                    jQuery('.t-current').text(thisListElement.text());
                thisReplacment
                    .find('select')
                    .val(thisValue)
                    .triggerHandler('change');
                var thisSublist = thisReplacment.find('.' + settings.className + '-list');
                if(thisSublist.filter(":visible").length > 0) {
                    hideList( thisSublist );
                }else{
                    showList( thisSublist );
                }
            }).bind('mouseenter',function(){
                jQuery(this).addClass('listelementhover');
            }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
                jQuery(this).removeClass('listelementhover');
            });
            jQuery('.' + settings.className + '-list', replacement).append(listElement);
            if(v.filter(':selected').length > 0) {
                jQuery('.'+settings.className + '-currentItem', replacement).text(v.text());
            }
        });
        replacement.find('.' + settings.className + '-moreButton').click(function(){
            var thisMoreButton = jQuery(this);
            var otherLists = jQuery('.' + settings.className + '-list')
                .not(thisMoreButton.siblings('.' + settings.className + '-list'));
            hideList( otherLists );
            var thisList = thisMoreButton.siblings('.' + settings.className + '-list');
            if(thisList.filter(":visible").length > 0) {
                hideList( thisList );
            }else{
                showList( thisList );
            }
        }).bind('mouseenter',function(){
            jQuery(this).addClass('morebuttonhover');
        }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
            jQuery(this).removeClass('morebuttonhover');
        });
        replacement.find('.' + settings.className + '-currentItem').click(function(){
            var thisMoreButton = jQuery(this);
            var otherLists = jQuery('.' + settings.className + '-list')
                .not(thisMoreButton.siblings('.' + settings.className + '-list'));
            hideList( otherLists );
            var thisList = thisMoreButton.siblings('.' + settings.className + '-list');
            if(thisList.filter(":visible").length > 0) {
                hideList( thisList );
            }else{
                showList( thisList );
            }
        }).bind('mouseenter',function(){
            jQuery(this).parent().find('.jquery-selectbox-moreButton').addClass('morebuttonhover');
        }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
            jQuery(this).parent().find('.jquery-selectbox-moreButton').removeClass('morebuttonhover');
        });
        _this.hide().replaceWith(replacement).appendTo(replacement);
        var thisListBox = replacement.find('.' + settings.className + '-list');
        var thisListBoxSize = thisListBox.find('.' + settings.className + '-item').length;
        if(thisListBoxSize > settings.listboxMaxSize)
            thisListBoxSize = settings.listboxMaxSize;
        if(thisListBoxSize == 0)
            thisListBoxSize = 1;   
        var thisListBoxWidth = Math.round(_this.width() + 2);
        if(jQuery.browser.safari)
            thisListBoxWidth = thisListBoxWidth * 1;
        replacement.css('width', thisListBoxWidth + 'px');
        thisListBox.css({
            width: Math.round(thisListBoxWidth-1) + 'px'
        });
    });
}
jQuery.fn.unselectbox = function(){
    var commonClass = 'jquery-custom-selectboxes-replaced';
    return this.each(function() {
        var selectToRemove = jQuery(this).filter('.' + commonClass);
        selectToRemove.replaceWith(selectToRemove.find('select').show());       
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to `bind()` change event, if you are using selectbox() jquery plugin

try this

```
 $('#per-page-select').selectbox().bind('change', function(){
      window.location = pager_url.replace('!REPLACEPAGE!', $(this).val());
});
```